# How to install font Inconsolata on MacTex 2014?

Tags: fonts, mactex

I try to install Inconsolata according to http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inconsolata/

I did the following steps:

Mac OS X: To install, open a Terminal window and cd to inside the downloaded TDS folder.

Method A (recommended): type

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c
sudo cp -Rfp * /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
sudo echo Map zi4.map >> /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/web2c/updmap.cfg
sudo mktexlsr
sudo -H updmap-sys
```

But when running `pdftex testfont` and I enter Inconsolata I get the following output error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.15 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/plain/base/testfont.tex

Name of the font to test = 
kpathsea: Running mktextfm Inconsolata
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation I for Inconsolata.
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Inconsolata
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2014) (preloaded base=mf)

kpathsea: Running mktexmf Inconsolata

! I can't find file `Inconsolata'.
<*> ...our; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Inconsolata

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...our; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Inconsolata

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: Inconsolata.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Inconsolata' failed to make Inconsolata.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
! Font \testfont=Inconsolata not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
<to be read again> 
                   \spaceskip 
\startfont ...ont \testfont =\fontname \spaceskip 
                                                  =0pt \leftline {\sevenrm T...

\init ...test = } \read -1 to\fontname \startfont 
                                                  \message {Now type a test ...
l.208 \ifx\noinit!\else\init
                            \fi
?
```

So what do I have to do now?

Comment: Have you tried inconsolatazi4 instead of just inconsolata. It got renamed at some point

Comment: I want to compile this book: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2-book and need to install Inconsolata as mentioned there. So I followed the steps on http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/inconsolata/ Is this inconsolata or inconsolatazi4?

Comment: You don't need to install it. It is part of MacTeX. Installing it will only create problems later. I recommend removing the files you installed manually, rerunning `sudo mktexlsr /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` and then running `sudo updmap-sys` again.

Comment: To use it: `\usepackage{zi4}`. Or `\usepackage{inconsolata}`.

Comment: Unfortunately the original code uses `\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-ansi]{Inconsolata}`. With this code I get errors. When replacing it with one of the above commands I get lots of other errors (not sure if the new ones are related to the inconsolata commands...)

Comment: As i mention, its name changed a while back. Use `\setmonofont{Inconsolata ZI4}` instead. Also, what are you using to compile your doc? Your code snipets seem to imply pdflatex. you shpuld probably use lualatex or xelatex if you code uses `setmonofont`

Comment: As @ArTourter says, if the document uses commands like that, you need Xe/LuaLaTeX. In that case, you should not load either of the packages I mentioned as they are designed for use with (pdf)LaTeX.

Comment: Looking at the source of the doc, it seems to expect to be compiled with xelatex, as the option xetex is passed to hyperref. There are a few weird things with that doc though, ie the use of both fontenc and fontspec, so one should probably be cautious with using it as a template.

Comment: If you have downloaded the whole tree, have you tried simply running `make` as the documentation instructs. That assumes of course that you are only trying to compile the document, and not use it as a template.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to compile `ggplot2-book`, and the following code replacement solves this particular error for me:

```
\setmonofont[Mapping=tex-ansi]{Inconsolatazi4}
```

Now it's back to the other one thousand errors involved in compiling this package...